# How many Fabrication Machines are there?

Tags: 9-2009

In the movie, *9*, we see the main villain, called the Fabrication Machine, also known as the B.R.A.I.N., which is capable of making other machines to serve as its army, for use in the annihilation of the 'stitch-punks', tiny ragdoll-like robots.

Do we know if there are others, and if so, are they just inactive? Or was this the only one? Does anyone know the answer?

Comment: Just the one, it seems; https://en-gb.facebook.com/9scientist/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One

There was one Fabrication Machine that we know of (the one seen in the movie). If there are any others, they are not hinted at or even mentioned. Moving into speculation here, I would say that there is one, and only one, Fabrication Machine in the world of 9.

Comment: Can you back this up with any evidence. For example from a viral campaign website that someone linked above?

Comment: who linked to what?

Comment: This one; https://en-gb.facebook.com/9scientist/

Comment: I do not pay attention to facebook

Comment: The same people who made the film also made a viral facebook site with backstory.